# Dynamic link to download file from S3 in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `message controller/model/view`, where user can send message to each other. I have added an attachment column for user to upload files when creating their message. I would like the recipient of the `message` to be able to download the attached file from S3 to his/her default download folder.
I have read several post, but none of them seem to address the dynamic angle.
Below is where I am now, in my controller:

```
  def download_url(attachment_file_name)
    s3 = AWS::S3.new.buckets[Rails.application.secrets.s3_bucket_name] # This can be done elsewhere as well,
    # e.g config/environments/development.rb
    url_options = {
        expires_in:                   60.minutes,
        use_ssl:                      true,
        response_content_disposition: "attachment; filename=\"#{attachment_file_name}\""
    }

    s3.objects[ self.path ].url_for( :read, url_options ).to_s
  end
```

and in the view:

```
  <%= link_to 'Download attachment', download_url(@message.attachment) %>
```

But this returns the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `download_url' for #<#<Class:0x00007fee04a12648>:0x00007fedf5c1d4d8>):
```

Which kind of makes sense. Does anyone knows how to do this please, i am surprise something that simple gets complex to me. help please - 4 hours in :(

Comment: you maybe need to move `download_url` method to `hellper`

Comment: Hey, i just moved it to a helper, now I get the following : uninitialized constant MessagesHelper::AWS. FYI in the helper i have :  require 'aws-sdk'
, and I am using the gem: gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3'. What am I not doing right please ?

Comment: maybe `Aws::S3`